# Propagation Of Error Calculation Of Incompressible Continuity Equation

Tags: fluid-dynamics, differentiation, error-analysis

Hello I am having trouble deriving the correct equation for error in vertical velocity from the incompressible continuity equation. We are trying to estimate vertical velocity ($w$) from the measurement of horizontal velocities $u,v$. The equation we are using is (assuming $w(0) = 0$)

$$w(z') = \int_{z'}^{0} \frac{\partial (u
)}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial (v)}{\partial y} dz$$

Where $z'$ is the depth at which we are interested in finding vertical velocity. We are trying to find the error in our calculation, to do so we are using the propagation of error equation (for independent random errors) from "Introduction to Error Analysis" by John R. Taylor. This would give us the equation

$$\delta w = \sqrt{(\frac{\partial w}{\partial u}\delta u)^2 + (\frac{\partial w}{\partial v}\delta v)^2}$$

However, I cannot figure out how to do $\frac{\partial w}{\partial u}$ or $\frac{\partial w}{\partial v}$, because $w$ is not dependent on $u,v$ but rather dependent on the spatial rate of change of these variables. Can anyone offer some insight please?

Comment: Can you numerically calculate the partial derivatives of $u(x,y,z)$ and $v(x,y,z)$? If so, you could also estimate their respective errors, then treat $u_x$ and $v_y$ as independent variables.

Comment: Excellent idea, thank you.